# Video file suddenly turning bad

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, file-corruption

I have several .mkv files of a TV show. Today, a very interesting thing happened to these files (only these files), and when played with VLC Player, the image is corrupted. When played with other video players, the image doesn't appear at all, just the sound.

There are several **intriguing** things with the problem.

- Only this TV Show's files are corrupted. (so figured, no codec problem or whatever, VLC runs other MKV files okay.)
- One day ago they were playing absolutely fine.
- The files were in a zip file at first, I did not delete the original zip files after I extracted the videos, the videos inside the zip appear corrupted as well. Which suggests there is no file corruption at all, given that the contents of a zip file wouldn't change.
- It appears the videos are not playing on other computers too. (which suggest they were corrupted from the beginning, but then what made them play fine before this happened ?)

After this many conflicts, I really don't know what to do. I don't actually care about the video files, just curious about what happened.

Couldn't decide which SE site to ask to question, I could move it if it's not convenient.

I had a hard time choosing tags, help is appreciated.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv9FC.png)

**Edit1:** I am using a Windows 10 Pro system.